# How can I get elit chromosoms much faster in GA(Genetic Algorithms)?

Tags: sorting, c#-4.0, genetic-algorithm

I am working on GA for Travelling Salesman Problem and I am using elitist selection. But to do this, I need to sort population order by chromosom's fitness values. This process is slowing down my application.Because the thread calls this process iteratively when new childs added into population. So I want to use another method to get some chromosomes have higher fitness values. How can I do that?

My code to get elits:

```
        Tour[] ElitChromosoms()
        {
            Array.Sort(population);

            Tour[] elits = new Tour[population.Length / 2];

            Array.Copy(population, elits, elits.Length);

            return elits;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some selection techniques require sorting, but there are others that don't. You can improve your program's efficiency by using them. You can use for example q-tournament.

Comment: Thanks. Now I am using tournament selection with group size 5. This does the same job with sorting at some points.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specifically a GA problem.

However, the problem you have (I think) is that your New Population is put in a list or array unsorted. If you add them to a sorted list, then you just need to get the top/bottom x for your elites.

This should be more costly in terms of time to insert, but still be faster than sorting from scratch.